# Using firestore data in state (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How do I go about setting a specific firestore document field to state.When ever i try to run this i get the following warning.

(Im trying to get an array from firestore if that helps)

**Possible Unhndled Promis Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: doc.data is not a function. (In 'doc.data()', 'doc.data' is undefined)**

```
class Chart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("users")
      .where("email", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        this.setState({ data: doc.data().prevlevel });
      });
  }
render(){
const data = this.state.data
.....
```

Comment: You're probably just missing a `catch()` to handle possible promise rejects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're firing a query against a collection. A query can have multiple results, and thus returns a `QuerySnapshot` and not a `document`. Even when there is only one document matching your criteria, it'll still be in a `QuerySnapshot`.

So your callback will have to iterate over the results. If you only expect one result, you could do that with:

```
db.collection("users")
  .where("email", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      this.setState({ data: doc.data().prevlevel });
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently getting a collection, not a document. If you want to get a doc, you'll need to add that to your request, as in:

```
    db.collection("users")
      .where("email", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .doc('someId') // <-- Added this, but i don't know exactly what id you need
      .then(doc => {
        this.setState({ data: doc.data().prevlevel });
      });
```

Or if you do want a collection, then you'll need to use the properties found on collections, as in:

```
.then(snapshot => {
  this.setState({ data: snapshot.docs });
})
```