# How to setState an entire collection in a firestore into an array in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, setstate

I want to setState a firestore collection called users into an array. The firestore collection contain documents and nested collections. I want to store them all in my array on the state. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Hi there, I have found several similar questions and this is why I have marked yours as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508459/cant-setstate-firestore-data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882140/using-firestore-data-in-state-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't setState Firestore data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508459/cant-setstate-firestore-data)